# Adding Custom Date Range on Admin Dashboard Chart Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I am working on a task to show Date Range on Dashboard chart. so data chart will display on custom date range selection. I have added calendar on chart but result is not coming properly. I know its very specific requirement. I am looking if someone has already done such modification and can provide me some guidence to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

The data displayed on the dashboard comes from tables aggregated by a cron every day for product viewed and bestsellers. It is calculated and displayed accordingly. If you want to have a date range, you need to use the ones that are aggregated daily and group by product_id. For orders, you can use the function **setDateRange** existing in **Mage_Reports_Model_Resource_Order_Collection**.